# Inheritance and types in C#

Tags: c#, oop

I'm having some trouble in allowing a Staff or a Person to "own" an account as per details below.

In the snippet below, on the Account class, I only accept `Person` as the owner. I kind of need to accept either a `Staff` or a `Person`

My main issue is that, later in the method `applyFee()`, I need to reach out the the owner object and if the owner has a feeDiscount property, I will need to use to calculate.
My issue is that since in the Account class the type is `Person owner` I am not getting the `feeDiscount` as it is null.

```cs
class Person
{
  public string name;

  public Person(string newName)
  {
    name = newName;
  }
}

class Staff : Person
{
  public decimal feeDiscount;

  public override Staff(string newName)
  {
    name = newName;
    feeDiscount = 0.5;
  }

}

class Account
{
  private decimal balance = 1000;
  private Person owner;
  public Account(Person newOwner)
  {
    owner = newOwner;
  }

  public void applyFee() {

    decimal fee = 100;

    if (owner != null)
    {

      if (owner.feeDiscount) {
        balance = balance - (fee * owner.feeDiscount);
      } else {
        balance = balance - fee;
      }

    }
  }
}

class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {

    Person person1 = new Person("Bob");
    Staff staff1 = new Staff("Alice");

    Account account1 = new Account(person1);
    Account account2 = new Account(staff1);

    account1.applyFee();
    account2.applyFee();
  }
}
```

Comment: The easiest solution is to give your `Person` a `feeDiscount` of `1`

Comment: @canton7 Sorry I was mistaken! You were right the first time

Comment: @MatthewWatson Oh no, I've missed the edit window to change it back now!

Comment: They're right, a fee discount of 0 would result in `100 * 0`, effectively a 100% discount

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want `Person` to remain as generic as possible, then you could make another class called `customer` who has a `feeDiscount` of 0.

So anyone who has any business spending money at a store, has some `feeDiscount`. This way, you can `applyFee` to a `Customer` or a `Staff` but not a `Person`

Comment: How could I define that the owner in the Account class can be either a Customer or a Staff? The way I found to do is to use the Person `private Person owner;` but not sure if that's correct.

Comment: You could leave it exactly as is and trust that `Account` is only fed `Staff` and `Customers`, or you could make `Person` and abstract class which says a `Person` can't be JUST a `Person`, it can only be used as the foundation to define other classes like `Customer` or `Staff`.